# Place variable into Python string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-interpolation

`var_a` (can be any variable name) should be replaced by its value:

```
var_a = "Hello"

var_b = "var_a world"

print var_b
```

Output should be: `Hello world`

Comment: Keep it simple... `var_a + ' world'`

Comment: It is not simple as you are saying. You have only string containing var names. Just need to evaluate variable which are unknown

Comment: Your question has no unknown variables

Comment: You dont know which variable will come in picture

Comment: I don't know what that means, but if you want to format a string using a variable, that variable must be "in scope". The contents of that variable doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

That exactly fits the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) description. You need to wrap the "part of the string you want to replace" with curly braces:

```
var_a = "Hello"

var_b = "{var_a} world".format(var_a=var_a)
```

It's also possible to use it without "names":

```
var_b = "{} world".format(var_a)
```

Comment: what if you dont know variable name in string?

Comment: @Swapnil Look at the second code block. The variable you insert (var_a) must be defined

Comment: var_a is not fixed variable how you add it format then?

Comment: @Swapnil Do I understand you correctly: You don't know in advance which _part of the string_ you want to replace? Or is it the variable name that should be dynamic?

Comment: Yes like ruby package = "Interpy" print "Enjoy #{package}!"

Comment: in that case I would advise to upgrade to python 3.6 and use f-strings: `var_b = f"{var_a} world"`. :) (you could use workaround to make it work on python 2.7 but it would be terribly inefficient and error prone).

Answer (score 0):

That is called variable substitution. You can do it by using <strike>format characters</strike> string formatting / interpolation operator in python. The code you wrote above would not work as you are expecting it to work.

For example, if you want to get the output you want to with variable substitution, you can do something like:

```
var_a = "Hello"
var_b = "%s world" % var_a
print var_b
```

This will output Hello world.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: You just have clean string and have to evaluate variables like ruby  package = "Interpy" print "Enjoy #{package}!"